# How to solve invalid date from strtotime()

Tags: php, date

I'm using the below HTML code in php file to display the date.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>    
<tr>
    <th>Posted on: </th>
    <td><?php $date1='{{posted}}';echo $date1 ;echo date("j-F-Y", strtotime($date1));?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</script>
```

In the above code `$date1` displays the value of a templated string.
For example the `echo $date1` displays 2013-12-09. But `echo date("j-F-Y", strtotime($date1));` displays `bool(false) 1-January-1970`. I know it is returning false because it is taking a negative value. But what should I do to accept the correct value and display the time as 9 Dec 2013.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = "2013-12-09"
$date = date_create($date1);
echo date_format($date,'j-F-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change date format using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) format() function like this:-

```
<?php
$source = '2013-12-09';
$date = new DateTime($source);
echo $date->format('j-M-Y'); 
?>
```

Output :-

```
 09-Dec-2013
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/yKiBOG)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?php
     $date1=date("F j, Y");  
     echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($date1));
?>
```